# Zend/Unit Testing: Checking variables after Model is called, before Controller is initiated

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, model, phpunit

I'm doing unit testing on a Zend Framework, and I'm presently testing functions in my model controller. At some point, one of the functions assigns:

```
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->assign('var_name', $someVar);
```

Because I have not called any controllers or views, I am unsure of how to view this data. I'd like to keep things isolated so my unit tests remain properly contained. Is there any reasonable way to grab this variable without modifying the function I am testing?

For reference, I am using PHPUnit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$someVar = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->var_name;
```

Comment: That throws an error, saying 'Trying to get property of non-object'. I am not in the same class as the place where that assign() is called. I am in a PHPUnit member class testing an instance of the Model class that makes this assignment.

Comment: That should work as long as the above line comes *after* your model class method that sets it executes. Note that `getMvcInstance()` will not create the instance if it's `null`. You must call `Zend_Layout::startMvc()` before trying to grab the instance.